# How do I change Drive with bash on windows?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just downloaded the new windows 10 update and I am trying to access some files on my F Drive using "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" but I can't seem to get it access my F drive. can anyone help? I have tried changing directories, and mounting the F drive.

Comment: Have you tried `cd /mnt/f`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### I can't seem to get it (bash) to access my F drive

In the Windows Linux subsystem your drives are mounted to `/mnt`.

So to change to drive F use the following command:

```
cd /mnt/f
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a removable drive, you may have to also mount it first: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

> In order to mount a Windows drive using DrvFs, you can use the regular Linux mount command. For example, to mount a removable drive D: as /mnt/d directory, run the following commands:
>
> $ sudo mkdir /mnt/d
>   $ sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
>
> Now, you will be able to access the files of your D: drive under /mnt/d. When you wish to unmount the drive, for example so you can safely remove it, run the following command:
>
> $ sudo umount /mnt/d